# Where else besides StackOverflow/SharePoint do we share knowledge?

Tags: office-365, learning

Of these 25 I can find a handful here on StackOverlflow
and only Marc Anderson is actively participating

I am on ITunity, I read Waldek's blogs, I try and understand the PnP hub and follow Jeremy on Twitter (why is he not in this 25 list?), I had never heard of five persons on this list and have disconnected from the Yammer group as it is impossible to keep up with.

#### What other places are there to learn?

[image]

1. [Naomi Moneypenny](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Naomi+Moneypenny)
   StackOverflow , [Blog](http://naomimoneypenny.com/) , [MVP](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/5001094?fullName=Naomi+Moneypenny) , [Twitter](https://twitter.com/nmoneypenny?lang=en) , [ITUnity](http://www.itunity.com/users/naomi-moneypenny) [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/manyworlds)
2. [Benjamin Niaulin](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Benjamin+Niaulin)
   [StackOverflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/10135/benjamin-niaulin) , [Blog](https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/) , [MVP](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/5000069?fullName=Benjamin+Niaulin) , [Twitter](https://twitter.com/bniaulin) , [ITUnity](http://www.itunity.com/users/benjamin-niaulin) [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/benjaminniaulin)
3. [Andrew Connell](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Andrew+Connell)
   StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
4. [Laura Rogers](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Laura+Rogers)
   StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
5. [Dan Holme](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Dan+Holme)
   StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
6. [Christian Buckley](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Christian+Buckley)
   StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
7. [Spencer Harbar](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Spencer+Harbar)
   StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
8. [Wictor Wilén](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Wictor+Wil%C3%A9n)
   StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
9. [Mary Jo Foley](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Mary+Jo+Foley)
   StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
10. [Waldek Mastykarz](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Waldek+Mastykarz)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
11. [Marc D. Anderson](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Marc+D.+Anderson)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
12. [Chris O'Brien](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Chris+O%27Brien)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
13. [Todd Baginksi](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Todd+Baginksi)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
14. [Joel Oleson](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Joel+Oleson)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
15. [Tobias Zimmergen](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Tobias+Zimmergen)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
16. [Dux Raymond Sy](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Dux+Raymond+Sy)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
17. [Todd Klindt](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Todd+Klindt)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
18. [Francesco Sodano](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Francesco+Sodano)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
19. [Vlad Catrininescu](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Vlad+Catrininescu)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
20. [Jasper Oosterveld](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Jasper+Oosterveld)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
21. [Dan Usher](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Dan+Usher)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
22. [Giuseppe Marchi](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Giuseppe+Marchi)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
23. [Patrick Hosch](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Patrick+Hosch)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
24. [Chris McNulty](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Chris+McNulty)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare
25. [Agnes Molnar](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sharepoint+Agnes+Molnar)
    StackOverflow , Blog , MVP , Twitter , ITUnity SlideShare

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw this list 1st time in one of the SharePoint Conf at Los vegas. Harmon.ie is the company who started this.

> We created the top 25 SharePoint Influencers guide by using the social
>   scoring system outlined in the book Socialized!. The formula takes
>   information gleaned from Twitter, Kred, Klout, SocialMention.com,
>   LinkedIn, Google+ and Alexa into account. For the first time, we used
>   a service called "Fakers" as part of the formula to eliminate
>   followers that are either inactive or are fake twitter accounts. Other
>   than that, this is the same research and methodology that has been
>   covered by the NY Times, Forbes and several other publications. We
>   also looked at each influencer in the context of Microsoft’s social
>   platform solution called SharePoint. Most either had a significant
>   focus on SharePoint, or were extraordinarily influential if they
>   discussed SharePoint.Take the top 25′s influencers whose score has collectively moved from an average impact rating of 3105 to 3883.3 this year – an increase of 25% over last year (see the analysis below) even with a slight change to the formula.

http://www.forbes.com/sites/markfidelman/2012/11/08/these-are-the-top-25-microsoft-sharepoint-influencers-for-2012/

Answer (score 6):

Most of the people on the list are MVP's in SharePoint and have a large popularity from their blogs, social media, community involvement, and books they've (co-)written. They have contributed a lot to SharePoint's success over the years. It is really just a marketing ploy/popularity contest in my opinion, which is shared by some others as well.

Jeremy isn't on the list because he is a Microsoft employee, which would be excluded from any survey like this.

Comment: Lets compile a list to all the blogs in the answer. I am not interested in the people or why they are on this 25 list, but their knowledge

Comment: To the Moderator @EricAlexander.. Just to improve my knowledge about the site.. Does these type of questions are valid here or they should go to Meta? Or may get converted to Community Wiki?

Comment: Wiki would be cool, where is it?

Comment: @DannyEngelman : We can mark our own answers as Community Wiki, but may be its Moderators who does that to questions.

Comment: Edit the post, tick the community wiki box in the lower right corner under the question text input.

Comment: @EricAlexander I am afraid such a tick is only seen for an answer, and not for a Question..

Comment: it is there on questions too

Answer (score 0):

[PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com) has courses from some of the people you mention above, as well as some others, including: Andrew Connell, Sahil Malik, Rob Windsor, David Mann, Bill Kulterman, Jeff Adkin, Liam Cleary, Tim Warner, and many more.  There is much "shared knowledge" there.

I agree with the comment above that its mostly a popularity contest.  Personally, I think that Sahil Malik, Andrew Connell, Rob Windsor, and Jeff Aidkin should be at the top of any such contest.